# Nvidia graphics problem with suspend and resume, system hangs

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, graphics, resume, sleep

Am on 11.04.  When I close my laptop lid (NVIDIA graphics - HP Pavilion)  it goes onto sleep mode.  But when I reopen it, instead of resuming onto the password prompt, it shows me a screen of random blocky colours - typically largely yellow.  I have to do a hard reset to restart the PC.  Here is an image I took of the problem:

[image]

Would file it on launchpad but not sure if it is a bug or isolated.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Does that pointer move ? Is numlock light blinking ? Are you running unity or gnome ?

here is some howto for debugging problems with suspend

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume

Comment: The cursor does move.  The numlock light doesn't blink but will switch on or off if I press the button.  I am running unity.

Comment: so, it is not problem with kernel panic. System resumes, but there is problem either with graphic driver or unity. Can you try running classic gnome panel session ( on login choose ubuntu classic ) ?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this for myself. I was having the same behavior, plus issues with Twinview. I found I was running the version 173 of the Nvidia driver, not the current recommended version.

**My setup:**

- Dell Latitude e6400
- Nvidia Quadro NVS 160M
- Using Twinview (but reproduces without Twinview too)

First, execute the following command:

~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

*NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  **270.41.06**  Mon Apr 18 14:54:25 PDT 2011
GCC version:  gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)*

If you see 173.x.x or 185.x.x or something you are out of date.

1. Open the Unity Dash (or something like System/Admininistration in Gnome)
2. Type "Additional Drivers" and select the app (or find the menu item in Gnome)
3. It should bring up a couple of entries for your Nvidia card. Install the "current version".
4. Reboot your machine

Things perform better for me after doing this, but not perfect.

Also, I found that I could also avoid this problem by logging in to the "Ubuntu Classic (no effects)" window manager. If you are really stuck, that may be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

For me the suspend/resume works again with nVidia GO 7300 with this workaround mentioned here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/728745/comments/73

1. Install libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental.
2. maybe you have to update your system with the x-swat ppa 
   (ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates)
3. Open the terminal and type the following commands:

   sudo update-alternatives --config gl_conf

and select the alternative provided by mesa.

```
sudo ldconfig
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf_old
```

You also have to install the nouveau driver.

and restart your computer.
After that I was able to suspend/resume my machine without graphic problems.

Hope this will help other.

Greetings.

Comment: I have already downgraded to the 173 driver because on the current one, I had the problem where if I had more than 2 windows open at once, any new windows would turn blank white.  Why can't they just release an update?

Answer (score 0):

If your video card is Agp, then the solution is to install the current Nvidia drivers from the Nvidia site and add the `Option "NvAgp" "1"` to section `"Device"` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

This forces the Nvidia driver to use Nvidia's built in Agp handling rather than Agpgart which nouveau is probably using.

**Details**

Download Nvidia's latest driver for your card.

Let the Nvidia driver installation do the blacklisting of the Nouveau driver when running the Nvidia driver install.

Copy the Nvidia driver file to `/home/$USER/Downloads`.

Using Terminal, update the headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

then log in as root using your password in tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd>), then `cd /home/$USER/Downloads`, then stop xserver: `/etc/init.d/mdm stop`, then run Nvidia driver install: `sh Nvidiadriverfile.sh`

I used `sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.37-pkg1.run.sh` then for Agp cards.

After reboot edit `the xorg.conf` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add `Option "NvAgp" "1"` to section `"Device"` to fix wake up from sleep problems for Agp cards (wake up from sleep problems also happen with the nouveau driver for Nvidia Agp cards).

Then install nvidia-settings utility.

Answer (score 0):

open `/etc/default/grub` using

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and add `nouveau.blacklist=1` at line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" "` 
and remove the `quiet` and `splash` to see the kernel messages .this blacklists the `nouveau driver` on bootup after suspend/hibernate

this worked for me on a `Dell Vostro 1500` with `GeForce8600`